# give permission admin role to someone

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

how to i give admin role of a document library to someone else?
Currently i am the giving access to folders in the document library for external and internal users. That means i am getting the mail from the users who requested the access to a folder or the document library itself.

I want this task to be given to someone else. i know they can provide the folder access. But how do i redirect the request mail to him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the below steps :

1. GoTo **settings** --> **Site Settings**
2. Under Users and Permissions, click **Site Permissions**.
3. On the Permissions tab, click **Access Request Settings**(refer following image).

[image]

4. Type the email address of the person you want to make responsible for approving access request (refer following image)

[image]

5. Done